# Are images generated on the fly in contextual image delivery

Tags: 2011, contextual-image-delivery

Are images generated on the fly while using contextual image delivery or is it stored somewhere in advance. I am looking for options to deliver device specific images to content delivery without creating multiple images for different devices. Also want to know if the contextual image delivery engine generate the images on the fly, is there any performance issue?

Comment: I had the same question, but it really has to be (should be) generated on-the-fly since you could virtually ask for any resize or crop (caching helps). However, you could optionally combine approaches. With an external content library (ECL) setup or using image variants, you could "bake" several variations, serving exact matches when appropriate. Some versions of Media Manager could help with that approach. Which makes me wonder if the amount of resize matters to performance, but that's another question. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- On the fly but cached so subsequent requests are fast.
- There could be some slightly delay for first user, but same can be compensated in image download as size would be small, it also depends volume of images being used on your web page.

refer this execellent [blog post](http://www.ianhomer.com/2014/04/sdl-mobile-contextual-image-delivery.html)